# 2017 Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Well, it's been a crazy month but July has finally come to a close and with it Stack Overflow's [9th moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9) has also concluded. [They said it was impossible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354024/is-the-election-unfair-or-am-i-wrong), but 30 thousand or so voters were able to pick the best two moderators from among many worthy candidates, namely:

[image: Andy] [image: Cody Gray]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5927932925050880/0).

#### November 2017 update:

After [a 2-year hiatus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311045/november-2015-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results), Jeremy Banks is stepping up to rejoin the moderator team. If you see him around, please give him a warm welcome!

Comment: Congratulations @Andy and @CodyGray! Well done and good luck! And thanks to the other candidates making the choice so hard for me ...

Comment: First time that all of my favorite candidates got elected. Congratulations to both of you!

Comment: @CodyGray: I hope that you will still find the time to stay active on Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray: See you in chat!

Comment: Code's comment on one of the linked posts now shows him as a mod. So satisfying

Comment: look, I called at least one of 'em. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353980/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-edits-on-my-own-posts-to-fix-english/353981#comment498351_353981

Comment: @Will: you should have left comments on *all* candidates posts, then deleted those that didn't make the grade later. ;-)

Comment: @Will now that deserves the precognitive badge.

Comment: I voted for both of these guys, I'm glad they won!  I am however quite concerned about two individuals who got too close for comfort to actually placing in this election as they both have fairly recent snooze closing records even in meta...

Comment: Thank you for the support everyone!

Comment: @Andy♦  did you change your name? I swear it used to just say "Andy"

Comment: @LordFarquaad The diamond was added automatically when I accepted the mod agreement on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Andy Oh I know, I was messing with you. Congratulations!

Comment: "*but 30 thousand or so voters were able to pick the best two moderators from among many worthy candidates*". Let me object to that sentence on a purely scientific basis. Just because people _chose_ doesn't mean that an optimum was reached. Furthermore, the whole statement assumes that "goodness as moderator" is an existing unique objective metric which is clearly not the case. I usually don't nitpick about these things but the fallacy ratio was just too damn high in the question :P

Comment: Congrats new mods! I think you'll do great.

Comment: @Andy Special congratulations for sticking through multiple elections. This is the third time I've voted for you. I'm glad you're on the mod team!

Comment: Congratulations for new diamonds! See ya in the chat rooms, never forget your duty to handle flags & keeping the site clean.

Comment: Finally - Andy was elected, i can stop voting for him.  And for years I kept hoping Cody would run. Glad he finally did.

Comment: Congrats Andy and Cody for this an important responsibility and faith given by the community. All the best.

Comment: @honk: [Don't worry about it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray?tab=activity&sort=all)

Comment: Congrats both of you.

Comment: Congratulations to Andy and Cody Gray.

Comment: Congratulations to the new Mods

Comment: @Andy Welcome aboard!

Comment: Congrats @Andy ATB

Comment: @BoltClock You confused me with that link! My view defaulted to showing "suggestions" which is empty! Next time don't forget the `...&sort=all` :)

Comment: Congratulations, Andy and Cody Gray.

Comment: @DavidG: Haha, I've [edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351100/should-i-flag-a-comment-for-editing-if-it-is-a-mix-of-chattiness-and-helpfulness/351101#351101) my comment.

Comment: congratulations team..

Comment: Great job guys. Congrats to you, and all of the users who participate in the election.

Comment: Congratulations to the brave souls who are newly tasked with the dual responsibility of maintaining law and order, while behaving :P .  Cheers, @Andy and Cody Gray. And all the best in your endeavours.

Comment: Both the peeps i wanted - well done guys! Does this mean @Andy has to pick a better profile pick? ;)

Comment: I can't remember who I voted for. :(

Comment: Congratulations!!! @Andy and Cody Gray.

Comment: You can still see your votes on the election page, @matt: https://stackoverflow.com/election/9?tab=election (the "primary" tab is available too, if you want it).

Comment: Congrats @Andy and Cody !

Comment: Who won the popular and who won the electoral?

Comment: I'm still surprised that they linked to my question in the post xD

Comment: @u8y7541 - How does a META post get -35 votes and get quoted in Moderator Election Results post?!?!  Well, -34 after I just upvoted it.  I got a bit of a mischievous flavor from reading it, and I love mischievous.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I don't know lol... I don't think it deserved that much downvotes

Comment: Wow, we have new mods

Comment: congratulation to both of you. Hope both of you will do everything here to make this community more valuable.

Comment: Welcome back to the team Jeremy Banks!  Now, maybe you'll be able to address a custom flag I've had in the queue for a few days... :)

Comment: Great, now the number of moderators is no longer divisible by 4 and [Undo is stuck alone on the last line in the list of moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). :-(

Answer (score 318):

Welcome Andy and Cody Gray! We have saved you some especially nice and juicy flags to get you started:

[image]

Let's get cleaning!

Comment: Oh... and I think we got 'em all, but there might still be some giant mutant rats in there that have one heck of a bite, so make sure you've got sturdy gloves and boots as you tidy up :p

Comment: @JonClements: I managed to take a snapshot of one: http://www.liftheavyrunlong.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rous.png

Comment: @JonClements why do I get the feeling there's a mountain of Private jokes that mods have somewhere, and that you give each other snide comments related to it?

Comment: *salutes* Private jokes. Be careful with those flags, I once knew a guy who got bitten by a radioactive flag. He got all the powers of a flag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters at least we don't have Flags of Unusual Size...yet.

Comment: good god. where is that picture taken?????

Answer (score 235):

Wow. I am honored and humbled. **Thank you to everyone who voted for me in the election! I very much appreciate all of your support**, and I hope that I will live up to everyone's expectations.

The field of nominees was truly outstanding, and I know that made the choice difficult. For those of you who didn't vote for me and/or were on the fence about my suitability, I hope that you aren't too disappointed in the outcome! :-) I meant everything I said about being open-minded and willing to consider alternative perspectives. If you disagree with any of the actions I am taking, please feel free to bring it to my attention. As long as this is done in a *constructive* fashion, I promise that I will be receptive to feedback.

I want to take this opportunity to specifically thank those of you who left supporting comments on [my initial nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9#post-45237399). Although I refrained from replying to each of you there to avoid cluttering up the discussion, I was deeply moved by several of the comments and thrilled to hear that I had the support of many members of the community whom I hold in the highest of regards.

I extend congratulations of my own to Andy, as well. He and I are joining a fantastic crew of individuals, all dedicated to making and keeping this wonderful corner of the web into the best resource that it can be.

And finally, for everyone who was testing earlier today to see if the chat-room ping feature actually works for my user name…indeed, it does. :-) Thanks again for the welcomes and wishes.

Comment: Congratulations Cody Gray sir.

Comment: Yeah everyone has to call you sir now, sir.

Comment: Yes sir, aye aye sir :) congratulations...

Comment: Congratulations and welcome!

Comment: For basically the first time ever in my Stack Overflow tenure, I am *really* curious why someone downvoted this post. I guess it means "you are not welcome."

Comment: may be its for getting your attention sir. It hard to really downvote this post. Welcome sir

Comment: In case you missed it: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=38329599#38329599

Comment: @Cœur In one day? In a week? For all time? I've been reviewing "not an answer" flags today. It's easier to work on a single type of flag at a time, rather than switching back and forth. I'll tackle close votes another time.

Comment: I was joking. Happy to see you helping.

Comment: Congratulations! Long overdue imho.

Comment: _"I am really curious why someone downvoted this post."_ - I thought you already knew the standard answers: "This is only a single downvote, shrug it off..." or "The car keys, you know..." ;)

Comment: Congrats Cody!, will we be able to drag you into chat if we need some advice?

Comment: Dragging is unsupported. I offer a command-line interface only. @Petter (But sure, if you need something, just holla. I monitor Meta more frequently than my own incessantly-overflowing inbox, though, for what it's worth...)

Comment: @Cody Sure I've been voting for you greybeard ;-).

Comment: I'm very glad you got the diamond. No one I would have rather voted for. Hope it doesn't take too much time away from your clearheaded and dead-on-principle Meta posts. If it does, though, at least it's because you have the ability to make the words into actions now. Trading "puissant" for "prolix" shouldn't be too bad. Good luck!

Comment: I am wondering which stud downvoted this post.

Comment: Congratulations, @CodyGray! See you when I see you. :D

Comment: I think you'll make an excellent moderator. You certainly have the experience on the site and the dedication. Great to have you on board. I grilled you, but more out of curiosity then anything. One thing for sure, you're highly intelligent and logical and we need that on the site. Oh I should add - I have nicknamed you the "anti-chatter" :D

Comment: Well done Cody and about time too :)

Comment: This is well deserved!

Comment: Belated congratulations, Cody! Now that the election is over, I don't mind saying that out of all the people I've seen meta posts from over the past several years, you are my all-time favorite, and I couldn't be happier to see you with a diamond here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Petter You can drag him, just don't drag 'n drop him afterwards - we want to protect his shiny new diamond

Comment: Happy to see you Cody Gray in moderator team. Finally both of my favourite nominees got elected :)

Comment: Congratulation @CodyGray Well Done...

Answer (score 166):

## Something is right on the Internet

That something is Stack Overflow.

Not every answer is right. Some are even completely wrong (and that's not a reason to delete them... yet). But, in my opinion, no other site has done what Stack Overflow has done to build a comprehensive library of correct technical Q&A.

All of this in spite of the INTERNET, where communities are beset on all sides by trolls, psychopaths, and constant argumentative complainers.

We rely heavily on the community to deal with these issues, but there are exceptional cases that require an elected mod.

## You now have even more power to help.

You can:

- suspend persistently uncooperative users and bust voting rings
- delete cluttering comments
- address flags and remove spam
- **deescalate situations with cool-headedness and respect**
- sign the mod agreement, fill out an email form, and maybe get a cool hat and t-shirt

You don't stop being a user when you become a mod. Please continue to write great questions, answers, and critical comments and otherwise engage in the community.

You also aren't expected to dive in immediately as an expert from day one. Learn and try to get it right. Apologize if and when you think you got it wrong.

### Things I wish I knew when I became a mod

- I don't have to deal with the first thing I organically come across with my mod hat.
- I don't have to deal with *everything* that I organically come across with my mod hat.
- I don't have to deal with *everything* that I come across in the mod review queue.
- Chat flags aren't super urgent. Now I usually leave them up so other mods (and especially community managers) have a chance to see them.
- My rules for myself as a user, while they work great for me, aren't the established principles we make everyone else follow.

Rules are important, but a lot of what we do involves subjective judgments, so take a step back and look at the context as well as the issue you're handling. (As an example, I've been deprioritizing comment cleanup on questions with few/no answers and few views - and the vice-versa.)

And that said, my rules for modding, while they work for me, aren't for all the other mods too. You'll talk to us, you'll be told if they think you're doing it wrong, and I think for the most part, you'll figure out your own modding rules and priorities for yourself (although Bhargav has written up a lot on things I haven't touched on much here and you should also peruse the mod help pages).

So don't stress out or worry about it too much. I'm glad to get some additions to the team.

Welcome aboard.

---

Dear users, if you're feeling inspired, please consider a few things that you could use that inspiration to do.

- Prioritize your flagging. Chattiness on a Q&A with 10 views and 1 answer isn't a big deal. On a Q&A with a million views and hundreds of new ones daily, you're making a big difference. Stack Overflow has a long tail of value of those low-view Q&A, but moderators only have so much time.
- Don't get into back-and-forths in comments. If comments to you are on your question or answer, just respond generically in your post, flag as applicable, then walk away.
- This site is not a big deal. Don't worry or stress about stuff too much. Log out if you find yourself stressing about one thing or another. You don't need to respond to every little thing.
- Asking is hard here, no matter how easy it might look. If you're having trouble with asking, understand that you're attempting something that isn't easy. Regroup, study, work to improve, and if it still doesn't come easy, just keep in mind that it doesn't come easy for me either.

Comment: Man. I feel kind of inspired, even though I haven't been elected to do anything.

Comment: "Prioritize your flagging" - doing this automatically seems like a lot better solution than expecting users to do it themselves.

Comment: That's an amazing post and should be pinned somewhere for all future mods.

Comment: @YvetteColomb well if you run again next year, then at least one future mod's seen it!

Comment: Nice post, why not add a last bullet point for all including mods (since we are not paid) that only Will have really understood:  **Have fun!**

Comment: Finally a good usage of the "Your Answer" part in the "Election Results" posts. Up until now I was always puzzled regarding the usage of this feature on these posts. It seem to be always used for bad jokes whilst you never know why one bad joke gets 100 upvotes while another similarly bad joke gets deleted.

Comment: @David Arenburg: I'd assume the reason we haven't been using the answer section for things like this is because this really ought to be somewhere more central and accessible via a link, rather than any one particular election results page.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess that makes sense. Maybe this indeed doesn't belong here rather at some internal page which only mods can see and add/modify its content.

Comment: Are voting rings really a thing now? My god, what gamification does to people.

Comment: @stybl: They have been for as long as the site has existed.

Comment: hi @aaron-hall, great post. Thank you

Comment: *Dear users* does that include mods? :p

Answer (score 46):

Welcome **Sir Andy** and **Sir Cody Gray** in the team of SO Moderator Elected crew.
It's really great that you have earned the faith of people and they have elected you.

We are saluting to you to spend and to be here for a long time.

[image]

I hope you will do everything here to make this community more valuable to all.

At the end, **congratulation** to both of you.

Comment: ... and some people very disappointed by _earned faith_ and down voted your post. :(

Comment: @Shashanth *It's really great that you have earned the faith of people and they have elected you.* maybe some people don't exactly agree it's really great, but that's just different opinions.