# How do I insert a user badge in a post?

Tags: support

I've just read the [2017 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354232/2017-community-moderator-election-results). There you can see the badges of two users inserted in the question. Unfortunately I cannot go to the "edit" section to be able to see the markdown.

How do I, if possible, insert a user badge in a question, other than cropping the badge and inserting it as an image link?

Comment: You can go to the post revisions (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/354232/revisions) - then pick "source" for a revision to view the markdown...

Comment: So it is an image. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6649786/wais-kamal/flair